# How do I customize SDCAlertView when using it in an Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, swift, sdcalertview

I am using SDCAlertview in a project, that is being developed in Objective-C, and I would like to be able to set the visual style but I am unable to do so.

The only file that I am able to import into any other obj-c class is `SDCAlertView-Swift.h` and that does not give me any options to set the visual style.

I have seen code samples, in swift, that are able to do this.

Can someone help me out here?

Thank You.

Comment: @scott-berrevoets developed this, may be he can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with exposing this API to Objective-C. That's fixed in https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView/commit/3f26a7851e1022e5aa65328ce9f36c63cdcb371a. This is not in master yet, but I plan on releasing an update in the next week or so.

Comment: Thats good news! When I couldnt find a solution, I simply customized the swift code itself to achieve what I needed. Thanks for the link to the commit!